# Is there a concept of event in Swift similar to events in C#?

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm getting into Swift from Java\C# background and can't figure out one thing. 
Is there any way to create a notification events in Swift objects similar to Events (`Action<T>`) in C#?

Or am I suppose to use closures for this purpose?

Comment: [Property Observers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID262), I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've understood it, an `Action<T>` delegate in C# is simply a `Void`-returning function delegate, which encapsulate a method that can be execute via the delegate.

Since Swift support higher order functions, you can define your own `Action<T>` type with the single purpose of encapsulating a `Void`-returning method for a single argument of the typeholder type T.

```
struct Action<T> {
    private let f: (T) -> ()

    init(_ f: @escaping (T) -> ()) {
        self.f = f
    }

    func run(_ val: T) {
        f(val)
    }
}
```

We can use this e.g. to encapsulate a function:

```
func addOneAndPrint(val: Int) {
    print(val+1)
}

let increaseAndPrintAction = Action(addOneAndPrint) // inferred to Action<Int>
increaseAndPrintAction.run(1) //2
```

or a supplied closure (similar to supplying a lambda to `Action<T>` in C#):

```
let increaseAndPrintAction = Action { print($0 + 1) }
increaseAndPrintAction.run(1) // 2
[1, 3, 5].forEach(increaseAndPrintAction.run) // 2 4 6
```

Now, I don't know the common use case of `Action<T>` in C#, but in case you want to use it to perform some event upon completion of some task, you might want to simply use a completion handler supplied as a closure to the task to be performed:

```
func increaseTask(_ val: inout Int, completion: (Int) -> ()) {
    val += 1
    // ...
    completion(val)
}

var val = 1
increaseTask(&val) { print("Successfully increased to value \($0)") }
    // Successfully increased to value 2
print(val) // 2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using delegates and protocols. Here is a simple example assuming you have a Storyboard with 2 ViewControllers called ViewController and SecondViewController (with storyboard id "Main").

```
protocol SampleProtocol: class {
    func didLoad()
    func didAppear()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, SampleProtocol {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let secondViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as! SecondViewController
        secondViewController.configure(delegate: self)
        addChildViewController(secondViewController)
        view.addSubview(secondViewController.view)
    }

    func didLoad() {
        print ("didLoad")
    }

    func didAppear() {
        print ("didAppear")
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: SampleProtocol?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        delegate?.didLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        delegate?.didAppear()
    }

    func configure(delegate: SampleProtocol) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other says there's no `event` keyword in swift. But it's easy to implement yours.

I've done a [swift package](https://github.com/MarcAlx/swift-event) that meet these requirements.

The [source code](https://github.com/MarcAlx/swift-event/blob/master/Sources/swift-event/swift_event.swift) is pretty simple less than 100 sloc.

Here's a short version :

```
public class Event<T> {
    private var handlers:[EventHandler<T>] = []

    private init() {}

    private func invoke(sender:AnyObject?,value:T) -> Void {
        for handler in self.handlers {
             handler.handle(sender,value)
        }
    }

    public static func += ( event: Event, handler: EventHandler<T>) -> Void {
    {
         event.handlers.append(handler)
    }

    public static func -= ( event: Event, handler: EventHandler<T>) -> Void {
         event.handlers.removeAll{$0 === handler}
    }

    public static func create() -> (invoke:Delegate<T>,event:Event<T>){
         let res = Event<T>()
         return (res.invoke,res)
    }
}
```

Where `EventHandler` is

```
///needed as Swift doesn't allow func ===
public class EventHandler<T> {
     private var _handle:Delegate<T>

     public var handle:Delegate<T> {
          return self._handle
     }

     public init(handle:@escaping Delegate<T>){
          self._handle = handle
     }
}
```

And `Delegate` is

```
public typealias Delegate<T> = (_ sender:AnyObject?,_ args:T) -> Void
```

Use asis :

```
let tmp = Event<String>.create()
var handler = EventHandler<String>(handle: { sender, args in
    print(args)
})
tmp.event += handler
tmp.invoke(self,"Hello world !")
//handler should print "Hello world !"
tmp.event -= handler
```

This solution offers near same syntax as C# : `+=`, `-=`, `Invoke` and prevents `invoke` call outside of declaration scope.